# ODE: Expected life time of an investment

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, economics

I was thinking on the following problem about ordinary differential equations applied in economics:
Compute the expected life time $u(S)$ of an investment on an asset at current price $S_0$ if it will sold whenever the price reaches $S_1<S_0$ or $S_2>S_0$ assuming that the price $S$ follows a random motion in one dimension with equal probability of jumping to the right and to the left.

To solve this problem I was thinking on the Poisson equation in one dimension, this is $$u''(S)=-1/k,$$ where $k=\lim_{\Delta t \rightarrow 0}\frac{\Delta S^2}{2 \Delta t},$ which is an ODE with boundary conditions $$u(S_1)=u(S_2)=0.$$

Is that right? In this case the expected life time searched is the solution of the previous equation with the two boundary conditions.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that sounds like a good plan.  And it is not at all difficult to solve that differential equation.

Comment: Yeah, this differential equation is really easy: just $$u(S)=\frac{-S^2}{2k}+c_1S+c_2,$$ ans using the b.c. we get that $c_1=\frac{S_1+S_2}{2k}$ and $c_2=\frac{-S_1S_2}{2k}$.